# How to vertically center a text in a column (bootstrap 4)?

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

How to vertically center a text in a column (bootstrap 4)? The structure is basic, see:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span>Text to center</span>
    </div
</div>
```

Ty guys!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can add the [my-auto](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/) class to the parent `<div class="col-md-6">` to achieve this. This class sets automatic margins on the y-axis, see the link above for more details.

It would look like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 my-auto">
      <span>Text to center</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might be tempted to use [vertical alignment](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/) utilities but these will only work on inline, inline-block, inline-table, and table cell elements.

Comment: Remember there is no longer `-xs` in Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 13):

Use **auto-margins** (`my-auto`), or use the **flexbox utilities**..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
            <span>Text to center</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
            ..
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/oy8H1bUOL1

Also, there are [several other **Bootstrap vertical centering options**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42252877/171456) explained in my other answer.