# Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am trying to center my Container in the middle of the page using Bootstrap 4. I have been unsuccessful thus far. Any help would be appreciated.

I have built it at [Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/cmseaton42/pen/EZMxem) so you guys can play with it and let me know what works as I am about out of ideas...

```js
var currentAuthor = "";
var currentQuote  = "";
function randomQuote() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: "method=getQuote&format=jsonp&lang=en&jsonp=?",
      success: function( response ) {
        $("#quote-content").html('<h2 id="quote-content" class="display-5"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"> ' + response.quoteText + ' <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>');
        $("#quote-author").html('<p id="quote-author" class="lead"><em>' + response.quoteAuthor + '</em></p>');
        
        currentAuthor = response.quoteAuthor;
        currentQuote  = response.quoteText
      }
  });
}

function openURL(url){
  window.open(url,'Share', 'width=550, height=400, toolbar=0, scrollbars=1 ,location=0 ,statusbar=0,menubar=0, resizable=0');
}

function tweetQuote(){
      openURL('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes,freecodecamp&related=freecodecamp&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + currentQuote + '" - ' + currentAuthor));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    randomQuote();

    $("#get-another-quote-button").click(function(){
        randomQuote();
    });

   $('#tweet').on('click', function() {
       tweetQuote();
   });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  background-image: url("https://www.mylinea.com/wp-content/uploads/beautiful-trees-stock-photo-055.jpg");
    background-color: #17234E;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 30%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}


.btn-new-quote {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #414147;
}

.btn-new-quote:hover {
    color: #0C0C0D;
    background-color: #9A989E;
    border-color: #0C0C0D;
}

#tweet {
    color: RGB(100, 100, 100);
}

#tweet:hover {
    color: RGB(50, 50, 50);
}


.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    opacity: .85;
    border-color:  RGB(50, 50, 50);
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="jumbotron vertical-center text-center">
                <h2 id="quote-content" class="display-5"><i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
                <p id="quote-author" class="lead"><em></em></p>
                <hr class="my-2">
                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-between">
                    <div class="col-sm-1-4 text-left">
                        <a id="tweet" href="#">
                            <h2 class="display-4"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1-4 text-right">
                        <button id="get-another-quote-button" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary  btn-new-quote">Don't Quote Me on This...</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1045, accepted):

***Important!*** **Vertical center is relative to the *height* of the parent**

> If the parent of the element you're trying to center has no defined
> **height**, *none* of the vertical centering solutions will work!

Now, onto vertical centering...

**Bootstrap 5 (Updated 2021)**

Bootstrap 5 is still **flexbox** based so vertical centering works the same way as Bootstrap 4. For example, `align-items-center`, `justify-content-center` or auto margins can used on the flexbox parent (`row` or `d-flex`).

- use `align-items-center` on a flexbox row parent (`row` or `d-flex`)
- use `justify-content-center` on a flexbox column parent (`d-flex flex-column`)
- use `my-auto` on a flexbox parent

[Vertical Center in Bootstrap 5](https://codeply.com/p/0VM5MJ7Had)

---

**Bootstrap 4**

You can use the new [flexbox & size utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) to make the `container` full-height and `display: flex`. These options **don't require extra CSS** (except that the **height of the container (ie:html,body) must be 100%**).

**Option 1 `align-self-center` on flexbox child**

```
<div class="container d-flex h-100">
    <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
     I'm vertically centered
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/fFqaDe5Oey

**Option 2 `align-items-center` on flexbox parent** (`.row` is `display:flex; flex-direction:row`)

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                I'm vertically centered
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

https://codeply.com/go/BumdFnmLuk

**Option 3 `justify-content-center` on flexbox parent** (`.card` is `display:flex;flex-direction:column`)

```
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col-6 mx-auto">
            <div class="card h-100 border-primary justify-content-center">
                <div>
                    ...card content...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/3gySSEe7nd

---

**More on Bootstrap 4 Vertical Centering**

Now that Bootstrap 4 offers flexbox and [other utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities), there are many approaches to vertical
alignment. http://www.codeply.com/go/WG15ZWC4lf

**1 - Vertical Center Using Auto Margins:**

Another way to vertically center is to use `my-auto`. This will center the element within it's container. For example, `h-100` makes the row full height, and `my-auto` will vertically center the `col-sm-12` column.

```
<div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-sm-12 my-auto">
        <div class="card card-block w-25">Card</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Auto Margins **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/akn5BYxQwn)

`my-auto` represents margins on the vertical y-axis and is equivalent to:

```
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
```

---

**2 - Vertical Center with Flexbox:**

[image: vertical center grid columns]

Since Bootstrap 4 `.row` is now `display:flex` you can simply use `align-self-center` on any column to vertically center it...

```
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

or, use `align-items-center` on the entire `.row` to vertically center align all `col-*` in the row...

```
       <div class="row align-items-center">
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-block">
                 Center
                </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-6">
                <div class="card card-inverse card-danger">
                    Taller
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

[Vertical Center Different Height Columns **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/GFgGl4YS27)

[See this Q/A to center, but maintain equal height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52913611/align-items-center-while-keeping-the-background-full-height)

---

**3 - Vertical Center Using Display Utils:**

Bootstrap 4 has [display utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/display-property/) that can be used for `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, `display:inline`, etc.. These can be used with the [vertical alignment utils](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/) to align inline, inline-block or table cell elements.

```
<div class="row h-50">
    <div class="col-sm-12 h-100 d-table">
        <div class="card card-block d-table-cell align-middle">
            I am centered vertically
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Vertical Center Using Display Utils **Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/30DYTbq83o)

**More examples**
[Vertical center image in `<div>`](https://www.codeply.com/go/Niu8NCcdqj)
[Vertical center .row in .container](https://www.codeply.com/go/7GgwkQhiro)
[Vertical center and bottom in `<div>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278082/bootstrap-4-text-vertical-align-in-the-center-and-the-end-of-div)
[Vertical center child inside parent](https://www.codeply.com/go/6V2zpJSbQO)
[Vertical center full screen jumbotron](https://www.codeply.com/go/9HWnyQm2Sf)

---

***Important!*** **Did I mention height?**

Remember vertical centering is relative to the **height of the parent** element. If you want to center on the entire page, in most cases, this should be your CSS...

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Or use `min-height: 100vh` (`min-vh-100` in Bootstrap 4.1+) on the parent/container. If you want to center a child element inside the parent. The parent must have a defined **height**.

Also see:
[Vertical alignment in bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313090/vertical-alignment-in-bootstrap-4)
[Bootstrap Center Vertical and Horizontal Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388989/bootstrap-4-center-vertical-and-horizontal-alignment)

Comment: When using above on a page with a navbar I'm getting a scrollbar. I think it's adding 100% height below the navbar and centering across it. How can I fix that?

Comment: I am trying to align multiple rows to centre with flex box. I want to align all buttons in centre.
 https://www.codeply.com/go/5abdqC33cU

Comment: I prepared a codepen currently showing 3 ways of centering based on the ways shown here: https://codepen.io/yigith/pen/oNjmGEL

Comment: Option 1 only worked for me when `<div class="container d-flex h-100">` was changed to `<div class="container d-flex vh-100">`

Comment: That's correct since `h-100` is 100% of its parent container while `vh-100` is height of the viewport. At the time the question was asked,`vh-100` didn't exist in Bootstrap.

Comment: @Zim can you please check this my issue. if you can help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031318/how-to-append-the-bootstrap-5-dropdown-menu-to-a-specific-element-when-the-drop Thanks zim.

Answer (score 50):

Using bootstrap version 5 or later, use the code below to center the content horizontally and vertically.

```
<div class="vh-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <h1>Centered horizontally and vertically!</h1>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You're the real MVP.

Comment: What about v5? This only centers it horizontally.

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Comment: This is the best way!  Works in BS4 as well

Answer (score 42):

you can vertically align your container by making the parent container flex and adding `align-items:center`:

```
body {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggEvQR)

Comment: ohhh lol, I missed the link in the description... you also added `html, body {height:100%}` ... adding that made it work! Thanks!

Comment: your answer doesnt solve the problem in the asked way (using bootstrap)

Comment: im totaly not agree with you, you propose to workaround despite of the question was about how do it with Bootstrap classes.

Comment: @AlexNikonov no where in the OP question does it say they are limited to using bootstrap only - this is an alternative for other people who may land on this page looking to vertically align things without the use of bootstrap classes.  Just move along - there are plenty of other answers here for you to use.  I don't see why you're getting hung up about this - this is a forum for all ideas that will help - not just single minded answers.  It is users like you spoiling this site by downvoting answers that offer a solution to the problem but just because you don't like it

Comment: @AlexNikonov also if you read the original unedited post (when I added my answer), you will also see OP was trying to centre without using bootstrap classes so at the time of answering, this was correct

Comment: Or with BS4: <div class="d-flex align-items-center">some text</div>

Comment: Didn't work for me under Bootstrap 5. CSS has too many interactions with itself.

Answer (score 41):

Following bootstrap 4 classes helped me solve this

```
<div class="col text-center justify-content-center align-self-center">
    <img width=3rem src=".." alt="...">
</div>
```

Comment: That didn't centered my div vertically though.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your css code. share a snippet of it, I would look into the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 19):

Because none of the above worked for me, I am adding another answer.

Goal: To vertically and horizontally align a div on a page using bootstrap 4 flexbox classes.

Step 1: Set your outermost div to a height of `100vh`. This sets the height to 100% of the Veiwport Height. If you don't do this, nothing else will work.  Setting it to a height of `100%` is only relative to the parent, so if the parent is not the full height of the viewport, nothing will work.  In the example below, I set the Body to 100vh.

Step 2: Set the container div to be the flexbox container with the `d-flex` class.

Step 3: Center div horizontally with the `justify-content-center` class.

Step 4: Center div vertically with the `align-items-center`

Step 5: Run page, view your vertically and horizontally centered div.

Note that there is no special class that needs to be set on the centered div itself (the child div)

```
<body style="background-color:#f2f2f2; height:100vh;">

<div class="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div style="height:600px; background-color:white; width:600px;">
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @AjayKumar, Would you like to share your modifications?

Comment: Thanks, especially the `100vh` trick helped me a lot. Bootstrap also provides the `vh-100` class for this.

Answer (score 15):

I did it this way with Bootstrap `4.3.1`:

```
<div class="d-flex vh-100">
  <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-center align-self-center">
    I'm in the middle
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: at last, something that works

Answer (score 13):

```
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
     <img src="/assets/images/ebook2.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 my-auto">
     <h3>Heading</h3>
     <p>Some text.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

This line is where the magic happens `<div class="col-md-6 my-auto">`, the `my-auto` will center the content of the column. This works great with situations like the code sample above where you might have a variable sized image and need to have the text in the column to the right line up with it.

Answer (score 7):

I've tried all the answers herefrom, but found out here is the difference between ***h-100*** and  ***vh-100***
Here is my solution:

```
      <div className='container vh-100 d-flex align-items-center col justify-content-center'>
        <div className="">
             ...
        </div>
      </div >
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 offset-1 d-flex">
            <div class="offer-txt justify-content-center align-self-center">
                <span class="inner-title">Our Offer</span>
                <h2 class="section-title">Today’s Special </h2>
                <p>One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, he found himself transformed in his bed into vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted his head a little he could see his brown belly.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: your pics made me thik the stackoverflow got started the advs :D

Answer (score 4):

In Bootstrap 4 (beta), use `align-middle`. Refer to [Bootstrap 4 Documentation on Vertical alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/):

> Change the alignment of elements with the **vertical-alignment**
>   utilities. Please note that vertical-align only affects **inline**,
>   **inline-block**, **inline-table**, and **table cell** elements.
>
> Choose from `.align-baseline`, `.align-top`, `.align-middle`, `.align-bottom`,
>   `.align-text-bottom`, and `.align-text-top` as needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<div class="container">
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center" style="height:100vh;">     
         <div>Center Div Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AjayKumar Adding the `flex-grow-1` class to the card prevents it from shrinking.

Answer (score 2):

Vertical align Using this bootstrap 4 classes:

**Method1:**

> parent: d-table
>
> AND
>
> child: d-table-cell & align-middle & text-center

eg:

```
<div class="tab-icon-holder d-table bg-light">
   <div class="d-table-cell align-middle text-center">
     <img src="assets/images/devices/Xl.png" height="30rem">
   </div>
</div>
```

and if you want parent be circle:

```
<div class="tab-icon-holder d-table bg-light rounded-circle">
   <div class="d-table-cell align-middle text-center">
     <img src="assets/images/devices/Xl.png" height="30rem">
   </div>
</div>
```

which two custom css classes are as follow:

```
.tab-icon-holder {
  width: 3.5rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
 }
.rounded-circle {
  border-radius: 50% !important
}
```

Final usage can be like for example:

```
<div class="col-md-5 mx-auto text-center">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
     <div class="tab-icon-holder d-table bg-light rounded-circle">
       <div class="d-table-cell align-middle text-center">
         <img src="assets/images/devices/Xl.png" height="30rem">
       </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab-icon-holder d-table bg-light rounded-circle">
       <div class="d-table-cell align-middle text-center">
         <img src="assets/images/devices/Lg.png" height="30rem">
       </div>
     </div>

     ...

    </div>
</div>
```

**Method2:**
You can use following:

> parent: h-100 d-table mx-auto
>
> AND
>
> child: d-table-cell align-middle

**Method3:**

You can use following:

> parent: d-flext align-items-center

also if you want content be center horisontally too:

> parent: d-flext align-items-center justify-content-center

Comment: align-middle is what I've been looking for, very simple and correct, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**bootstrap 5 and blazor web assembly:**

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min" style="height: 50vh">
<button class="btn btn-outline-success mx-2">Register</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary mx-2" style="width:123.44px">Login</button></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

/*You have to add height 100vh */

Center

Answer (score 0):

use `.my-auto` (bootsrap4) css class on yor div

Answer (score 0):

Place your content within a flexbox container that is 100% high i.e h-100. Then justify the content centrally by using *justify-content-center* class.

```
<section class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="jumbotron my-auto">
        <h1 class="display-3">Hello, Malawi!</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

in Bootstrap 5 we can do it easily. Below is an example to align card. We just have to set the card width, then the rest setting are using bootstrap 5 class.

```
<div class="container d-flex vh-100">
  <div class="row mx-auto">
    <div class="col align-self-center p-4">
      <div class="card rounded-3 shadow-sm p-3" style="width:400px">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1>I'am centered vertically and horizontally</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For all **Bootstrap versions 2, 3, 4 and 5** with only two custom classes suitable with any height and width.

[image]

```css
.d_tbl{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

.d_tblCel{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="d_tbl" style="background-color:antiquewhite">
    <div class="d_tblCel">
      <h3>Centered horizontally and vertically</h3>
      <p>for all bootstrap versions with only two custom classes</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is not the bootstrap way to do it

Answer (score -2):

In Bootstrap 4.1.3:

This worked for me when I was trying to center a bootstrap badge inside of a `container > row > column` next to a `h1` title.

What did work was some simple css:

```
.my-valign-center {
  vertical-align: 50%;
}
```

or

```
<span class="badge badge-pill" style="vertical-align: 50%;">My Badge</span>
```