# Vertical alignment in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to have a center text over image. I've used [mx-auto](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering) to Horizontal centering my overlay text and use [align-middle](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/vertical-align/) for a Vertical alignment. But the vertical alignment didn't work. Does somebody know why ?

```html
  

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

      <div class="card ">
<img class="img-fluid card-img" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature">
<div class="card-img-overlay d-flex">
  <div class="mx-auto">
<h4 class="card-title align-middle">Animal Farm</h4>
<h6 class="text align-middle">George Orwell</h6>
<p class="card-text align-middle">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society...</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `my-auto` for **vertical center**...

```
  <div class="card">
        <img class="img-fluid card-img" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature">
        <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex">
            <div class="my-auto mx-auto text-center">
                <h4 class="card-title">Animal Farm</h4>
                <h6 class="text">George Orwell</h6>
                <p class="card-text">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/ZQM4ANFcXC

`align-middle` will work on `display: table` or `display: inline` elements.

Also see this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4/42252877#42252877)

Comment: Is there any reason why it wouldn't be better to use `m-auto` instead of `my-auto mx-auto` ?

Comment: if you wanted both horizontal and vertical center use `m-auto`. I used both because the question was only about vertical center and I wanted to distinguish the use of `my-auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `.mx-auto`. You can just use `.justify-content-center`,  `.align-items-center` and `.flex-column` on the parent. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="card ">
  <img class="img-fluid card-img" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature">
  <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center flex-column">
      <h4 class="card-title align-middle">Animal Farm</h4>
      <h6 class="text align-middle">George Orwell</h6>
      <p class="card-text align-middle">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this code, here:

```
<div class="card ">
<img class="img-fluid card-img" src="https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/960w/1U2EGZ07GU.jpg" alt="Deer in nature">
<div class="card-img-overlay d-flex">

<div class="mx-auto" style="margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto;">
<h4 class="card-title">Animal Farm</h4>
<h6 class="text">George Orwell</h6>
<p class="card-text">Tired of their servitude to man, a group of farm animals revolt and establish their own society...</p>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Basically just added `style="margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto;"` to the div with mx-auto class.