# Vertically Center Text Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to center **vertically** my text inside a

> div class="col-md-6"

and have the same height

Example:

[image: ...]

Comment: put class="text-center" to your text

Comment: Will the text wrap onto two lines? If not, you can just use the CSS `line-height` property, and set it to match your fixed height.

Comment: @this.girish That will center the text **horizontally**...

Comment: oops, got confused in horizontal and vertical, my bad

Comment: this link might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548578/7714663

Comment: helpful, working for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69777645/7186739

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use margin-top:50%; to the text;

```css
.vertical{
margin-top:50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img alt="img" src="http://asianmeditour.com/assets/images/post/1542457653tourism.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3 class="vertical">Column 3</h3>        
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works well if the text is only 1 line, but how about a text with multple lines ? (the top margin will be 50%, but the white space in the bottom won't be 50%

Comment: @Gers did you find any solution

Comment: @Mri I can't really remember if I did at that moment. But one thing you can do is to use CSS' **align-items** property.  It seems it's supported by most browser now, so it should do the trick
The code would look like `<div style="align-items: center"><span>Your awesome content</span></div>`

Comment: documentation reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Answer (score 21):

this is bootstrap 4:

```html
<html><head>    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">
    <img src="https://media.haircutinspiration.com/photos/20181204011855/boy-hairstyle-e1536810585307.jpg" class="img-fluid">
</div>
    <div class="col-6 align-self-center">
        hello hello
    </div>

</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: `align-self-center` on the column did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Check my snippet it will work as you want ...

```css
.content_center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center; 
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  border : 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content_center col-md-6">
What I want
</div>
```

Comment: This is the proper solution if you intend to align both horizontally (justify-content: center) and vertically (align-items: center), both with a set height, and the display: flex option.

Answer (score 15):

Define a custom class and use as follows:

```css
.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-align">
        <div class="col-md-6"><img src=" http://placehold.it/150x50" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Dummy text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

in Bootstrap 4,
 use the class **align-self-center** in the parent element.

```
<div class="align-self-center">
    hello hello
</div>
```

Comment: parent element is the key distinction.

Comment: @Shneor I switched from a snippet to a regular code block, since a runnable demo requires quite a bit more boilerplate. I considered adding said boilerplate, but it would ruin the simplicity of this example.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the height, then set line height equal to height of div if there is single line.

If more than one line.

### HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6 floatingDiv">
    This should be in the middle
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.floatingDiv {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try following css on your text element:

```
.className{
    position: relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, and doesn't even need bootstrap to work!

Answer (score 2):

Based on Bootstrap 4, which is now flex-based, you can use the `align-items-center` utility on a Bootstrap `row` to vertically centre the row's content.

For instance:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img alt="img" src="http://asianmeditour.com/assets/images/post/1542457653tourism.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      Text vertically centred!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/540xf89j/).

I found about the `align-items-center` keyword [here](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-4-vertical-center-1211448a2eff).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="col-md-6" style="height: 450px;background-color: red;"> 
       <div class="v_align">
            What i have

       </div> 
</div>

<style>
.v_align {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
}
</style>
```