# Bootstrap 4 vertically align center not working on flex layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I have a responsive layout with 3 columns, that (should) change order, width, and horizontal alignment on different screen sizes. It all works fine except that the horizontal center alignment of the imgs on screensize <768px does not work. Here's my code:

```css
.icon-xl-large {
  width: 80px;
}

.w-400px {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-md-between">
  <div class="order-md-1 col-6 col-md-auto align-self-center">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="" class="icon-xl-large mx-auto" >
  </div>
  <div class="order-md-3 col-6 col-md-auto align-self-center">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="" class="icon-xl-large mx-auto" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 order-md-2 col-md-6 w-400px text-center">
    <h5>Sample text in center</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my example code the imgs in the 2 columns both align left. The expected behavior should be that both imgs align vertically center in their respective column. On screensize >768px the columns of the imgs automatically float to the left and right (col-md-auto). This is expected and should not be changed.

**How can I center the imgs in their column on screensize <768px?**

I found similar questions such as  [Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4) and tried various suggested solutions, e.g. setting mx-auto, justify-content-center with d-flex, setting a fixed width, etc. Nothing seems to work for me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can give the divs containing the images : text-align: center.
For instance:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .col-6.col-md-auto.align-self-center {
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `.mx-auto` to work, you need `.d-block`. [Aligning images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#aligning-images).

```
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x350" alt="" class="icon-xl-large mx-auto d-block">
```