# How to center to the screen a div content with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 and I would like to **center container content**, which means it showing exactly on the center of the screen. However, my content is still stuck on the top side, even if height is 100% and I use `justify-content-center align-items-center`

**Image:**

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body class="h-100">

  <header>
    ...
  </header>

  <main class="h-100">

    <div class="container h-100">

      <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col">

          <!-- Title -->
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div id="title" class="w-100 mt-5">
              <h1>Let's Find You a Great Apartment.</h1>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Subtitle -->
          <div class="row text-center">
            <div id="subtitle" class="w-100">
              <h2><small>Join more than 5,828,476 happy renters searching 1,025,792 local apartments.</small></h2>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Search box -->
          <div class="row w-100 align-items-center">
            <div id="search" class="enterALocationSearchBox mt-2">
              <input type="text" class="w-100" placeholder="Enter a Location here">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </main>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous" />

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add `h-100` in your `row` as well

Comment: Have you seen <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4/42252877#>?

Comment: I actually read all those. I forgot one **h-100** and now everything works.

Answer (score -1):

You don't even need bootstrap for that.

You can use `position: relative` for parent div and `position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` for child then the child will be in middle of parent. But remember to set parent height and width to correct value.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

More info about css centering [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

---

If you insist on using bootstrap for that, you need to specify height of parent div to make vertical centering working.