# Bootstrap 4 vertical align center and bottom of div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I use Bootstrap 4. `.top` block should be 100% width and full screen height. `.top-title` should be in the middle of screen. `.btn-scroll-down` shold be down of the screen.

I want my page looks like [image]

**HTML**

```
<!-- top -->
        <div class="top js-top">
            <div class="container h-100">
                <div class="row h-100">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1 class="top-title">
                            <span class="top-title-1">text</span>
                            <span class="top-title-2">title</span>
                            <span class="top-title-3">text</span>
                        </h1>
                        <a href="" class="btn-redirect link-go-to-match">go</a>

                        <a href="#" class="btn-scroll-down js-btn-scroll-down"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <!-- /top -->
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-redirect {
    display: block;
    width: 301px;
    height: 57px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ff780c;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.btn-scroll-down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2%;
    left: 50%;
    display: block;
    width: 54px;
    height: 54px;
    margin-left: -27px;
    content: '';
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s;
    opacity: .5;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}

.top
{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(../images/bg_main.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: red;
}
.top .top-title
{
    padding-top: 35vh;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
}
.top .top-title .top-title-1
{
    font-family: 'RobotoRegular';
    font-size: 3vh;
    display: block;
}
.top .top-title .top-title-2
{
    font-family: 'DaysOneRegular';
    font-size: 15vh;
    line-height: 1;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
.top .top-title .top-title-3
{
    font-family: 'RobotoRegular';
    font-size: 3vh;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2vh;
}
.top .link-go-to-match
{
    margin: 2vh auto 0 auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LL0xm1jg/4/

But on the small screen `.btn-redirect` is placed on texts

[image]

I've tried to use `flex` properties from Bootstrap 4 but my attempts failed. Is there any way to make it work properly?

Comment: The Best way would be to use media query for smaller screens.Add padding-bottom to avoid the overlap.

Comment: padding-bottom! exactly! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **flexbox** way. Add a flexbox util class for the container to fill height. This `flex-fill` class will be [included in Bootstrap 4.1](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/2137d61eacbd962ea41e16a492da8b1d1597d3d9).

```
.flex-fill {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/YUw4uBdG1O

```
<div class="top js-top vh-100 bg-danger text-white d-flex">
    <div class="container flex-fill">
        <div class="row h-100 align-items-center py-1">
            <div class="col-lg-12 h-100 flex-fill d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
                <div class="my-auto text-center">
                    <h1 class="top-title">
                        <span class="top-title-1">text</span>
                        <span class="top-title-2">title</span>
                        <span class="top-title-3">text</span>
                    </h1>
                    <a href="" class="btn btn-redirect link-go-to-match">go</a>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="btn-scroll-down js-btn-scroll-down"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Make the `col-lg-12` a flexbox column using `d-flex flex-column` and then group the h1 and go button together in a div. Use `my-auto` to vertically center that div, and the button will naturally push to the bottom.

Comment: Thanks! But I also need to put arrow inside `.btn-scroll-down` http://prntscr.com/ir38lx I used pseudo-element `:before` with `position: absolute` for this purpose but now `.btn-scroll-down` doesn't have position property, so `:before` is not placed in right place. How to fix it?

Comment: I forgot to copy this part of code in jsfiddle, sorry, my mistake ;-( It's updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/LL0xm1jg/7/ But I added `position: relative;` to `.btn-scroll-down` and it seems it fixed my problem with arrow. But I see other problem - in narrow screen `.btn-scroll-down` is changing its sizes http://prntscr.com/ir3kyh Is it fixible?

Comment: It's because you have `height: 22px`.. just use `width: 36px; height:36px;`

Comment: nonono, it's :before element which has height:22px and width:36px, but the problem is .btn-scroll-down is becoming oval from round

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks a lot for the help!