# Vertically center elements in a div - CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I need to vertically center my contents in a div. The second div SEEMS to be centered but the first one is not. I need to center both of them including their children VERTICALLY inside the div.

Example:

```css
[type='file'] {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
  &:focus {
    +label {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #137cbd, 0 0 0 3px rgba(19, 124, 189, 0.3) !important;
    }
  }
}

.PcYqm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.gYoMm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.eZmlQJ {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
}

.bcHrqA {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Style dependencies -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@^7.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Blueprint stylesheets -->
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/icons@^3.4.0/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/core@^3.10.0/lib/css/blueprint.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="bp3-card bp3-elevation-1 p-2">
  <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 PcYqm">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="justify-content-between row h-100">
        <div class="d-flex col-4">
          <div class="bp3-button-group align-items-center"><span class="bp3-popover-wrapper"><span class="bp3-popover-target"><span icon="help" tabindex="0" class="bp3-icon bp3-icon-help bp3-intent-primary"><svg data-icon="help" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <desc>help</desc>
                            <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8s3.58 8 8 8 8-3.58 8-8-3.58-8-8-8zm1 13H7v-2h2v2zm1.93-6.52c-.14.32-.35.64-.62.97L9.25 8.83c-.12.15-.24.29-.28.42-.04.13-.09.3-.09.52V10H7.12V8.88s.05-.51.21-.71L8.4 6.73c.22-.26.35-.49.44-.68.09-.19.12-.38.12-.58 0-.3-.1-.55-.28-.75-.18-.19-.44-.28-.76-.28-.33 0-.59.1-.78.29-.19.19-.33.46-.4.81-.03.11-.1.15-.2.14l-1.7-.25c-.12-.01-.16-.08-.14-.19.12-.82.46-1.47 1.03-1.94.57-.48 1.32-.72 2.25-.72.47 0 .9.07 1.29.22s.72.34 1 .59c.28.25.49.55.65.89.15.35.22.72.22 1.12s-.07.75-.21 1.08z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                          </svg></span></span>
            </span>
            <h4 class="bp3-heading UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 d-flex"><span class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 bcHrqA">Export</span><img alt="" src="/static/media/export.846774e4.svg"></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto align-items-center" style="
">
          <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 gYoMm h-100"><input type="file" id="uploadFileExport" accept=".xlsm"><label for="uploadFileExport" class="bp3-button bp3-intent-primary"><span>Select file</span></label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 eZmlQJ">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="justify-content-between row">
        <div class="d-flex col-4">
          <div class="bp3-button-group align-items-center"><span class="bp3-popover-wrapper"><span class="bp3-popover-target"><span icon="help" tabindex="0" class="bp3-icon bp3-icon-help bp3-intent-primary"><svg data-icon="help" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <desc>help</desc>
                            <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8s3.58 8 8 8 8-3.58 8-8-3.58-8-8-8zm1 13H7v-2h2v2zm1.93-6.52c-.14.32-.35.64-.62.97L9.25 8.83c-.12.15-.24.29-.28.42-.04.13-.09.3-.09.52V10H7.12V8.88s.05-.51.21-.71L8.4 6.73c.22-.26.35-.49.44-.68.09-.19.12-.38.12-.58 0-.3-.1-.55-.28-.75-.18-.19-.44-.28-.76-.28-.33 0-.59.1-.78.29-.19.19-.33.46-.4.81-.03.11-.1.15-.2.14l-1.7-.25c-.12-.01-.16-.08-.14-.19.12-.82.46-1.47 1.03-1.94.57-.48 1.32-.72 2.25-.72.47 0 .9.07 1.29.22s.72.34 1 .59c.28.25.49.55.65.89.15.35.22.72.22 1.12s-.07.75-.21 1.08z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                          </svg></span></span>
            </span>
            <h4 class="bp3-heading UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 d-flex"><span class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 bcHrqA">Submit</span><img alt="" src="/static/media/submit.0c47fc11.svg"></h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 gYoMm h-100"><input type="file" id="uploadFileSubmit" accept=".xlsm"><label for="uploadFileSubmit" class="bp3-button bp3-intent-primary"><span>Select file</span></label></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advice. I can use bootstrap as well.

Comment: Does the parent have a fixed height? And maybe it would be helpful, if you'd tell us which you want to be centered

Comment: Nope. Not as of now. But I am happy to include one.

Comment: If a fixed height is not necesary, use `margin: 3rem 0;` on a wrapper you wrap the items-to-be-centered in , easiest way I can imagine.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: Sure! It will take 1 mins

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4

Comment: Added an answer, I forgot to ask tho, if you want both items on the same line or underneath each other

Comment: Items inside the red box should be center aligned and items inside green box should be center aligned as well. Additionally, both red and green boxes should be horizontally centered inside the container, leaving same padding  in top, middle and bottom.

Comment: Like so? https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/jOqmvMK

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Here directly incorporated into your HTML.

```css
[type='file'] {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;

  &:focus {
    + label {
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #137cbd, 0 0 0 3px rgba(19, 124, 189, 0.3) !important;
    }
  }
}

.PcYqm {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: red;
}

.UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.gYoMm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.eZmlQJ {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: green;
}

.bcHrqA {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
        <!-- Style dependencies -->
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@^7.0.0" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Blueprint stylesheets -->
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/icons@^3.4.0/lib/css/blueprint-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/core@^3.10.0/lib/css/blueprint.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <div class="bp3-card bp3-elevation-1 p-2">
          <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 PcYqm">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center row p-2">
                <div class="d-flex col-4">
                  <div class="bp3-button-group align-items-center"><span class="bp3-popover-wrapper"><span class="bp3-popover-target"><span icon="help" tabindex="0" class="bp3-icon bp3-icon-help bp3-intent-primary"><svg data-icon="help" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <desc>help</desc>
                            <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8s3.58 8 8 8 8-3.58 8-8-3.58-8-8-8zm1 13H7v-2h2v2zm1.93-6.52c-.14.32-.35.64-.62.97L9.25 8.83c-.12.15-.24.29-.28.42-.04.13-.09.3-.09.52V10H7.12V8.88s.05-.51.21-.71L8.4 6.73c.22-.26.35-.49.44-.68.09-.19.12-.38.12-.58 0-.3-.1-.55-.28-.75-.18-.19-.44-.28-.76-.28-.33 0-.59.1-.78.29-.19.19-.33.46-.4.81-.03.11-.1.15-.2.14l-1.7-.25c-.12-.01-.16-.08-.14-.19.12-.82.46-1.47 1.03-1.94.57-.48 1.32-.72 2.25-.72.47 0 .9.07 1.29.22s.72.34 1 .59c.28.25.49.55.65.89.15.35.22.72.22 1.12s-.07.75-.21 1.08z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                          </svg></span></span></span>
                    <h4 class="bp3-heading UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 d-flex"><span class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 bcHrqA">Export</span><img alt="" src="/static/media/export.846774e4.svg"></h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto align-items-center" style="
">
                  <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 gYoMm h-100"><input type="file" id="uploadFileExport" accept=".xlsm"><label for="uploadFileExport" class="bp3-button bp3-intent-primary"><span>Select file</span></label></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 eZmlQJ">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="justify-content-center align-items-center row p-2">
                <div class="d-flex col-4">
                  <div class="bp3-button-group align-items-center"><span class="bp3-popover-wrapper"><span class="bp3-popover-target"><span icon="help" tabindex="0" class="bp3-icon bp3-icon-help bp3-intent-primary"><svg data-icon="help" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <desc>help</desc>
                            <path d="M8 0C3.58 0 0 3.58 0 8s3.58 8 8 8 8-3.58 8-8-3.58-8-8-8zm1 13H7v-2h2v2zm1.93-6.52c-.14.32-.35.64-.62.97L9.25 8.83c-.12.15-.24.29-.28.42-.04.13-.09.3-.09.52V10H7.12V8.88s.05-.51.21-.71L8.4 6.73c.22-.26.35-.49.44-.68.09-.19.12-.38.12-.58 0-.3-.1-.55-.28-.75-.18-.19-.44-.28-.76-.28-.33 0-.59.1-.78.29-.19.19-.33.46-.4.81-.03.11-.1.15-.2.14l-1.7-.25c-.12-.01-.16-.08-.14-.19.12-.82.46-1.47 1.03-1.94.57-.48 1.32-.72 2.25-.72.47 0 .9.07 1.29.22s.72.34 1 .59c.28.25.49.55.65.89.15.35.22.72.22 1.12s-.07.75-.21 1.08z" fill-rule="evenodd"></path>
                          </svg></span></span></span>
                    <h4 class="bp3-heading UtilClasses_NO_MARGINS__lwdL1 d-flex"><span class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 bcHrqA">Submit</span><img alt="" src="/static/media/submit.0c47fc11.svg"></h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto">
                  <div class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 gYoMm h-100"><input type="file" id="uploadFileSubmit" accept=".xlsm"><label for="uploadFileSubmit" class="bp3-button bp3-intent-primary"><span>Select file</span></label></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Former post**:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #2196f3;
}

.container > .wrapper {
  padding: 3rem 0;
}

/* optional */

span {
  display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span class="item-1">
      Item 1
    </span>
    <span class="item-2">
      Item 2
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are btw a thousand ways to center something vertically, you could use `flex-box`, or a mixture out of `position: absolute`, `top: 50%` and `transform: translateY(-50%)`, works all.

Comment: Do you mind if you can get me something from the working code I have?

Comment: Tried it. Didnt work. https://jsfiddle.net/q93a2rec/

Comment: its because you were using it on the wrong containers, I'm fixing it rn

Comment: @a2441918, updated my answer, just copy the HTML from the first snippet.

Comment: Well, the buttons are not aligned. They are stacked one below the other which is not expected.

Comment: @a2441918 you didn't use the word *horizontally*, fixed it anyways, check...

Comment: @a2441918, in case you wonder, why they are not next to each other, its because `input type="file"` has a fixed width defined by the `agend-sheet`, you can only edit that using Javascript

Comment: Thanks buddy..... One minor nitpick is that the submit button in the red box is more closer to the top, than the submit button in the green box

Answer (score 2):

In your css file, make these changes:

```
.PcYqm {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px; // added this
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.eZmlQJ {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px; // added this
  margin: 10px;
  background: green;
}
```

Next in your HTML labels for both "Select File", add this CSS:

```
<label for="uploadFileExport" style="margin-top: .5rem" ... 
<label for="uploadFileSubmit" style="margin-top: .5rem" ...
```

Instead of this inline CSS, you can also create a class but that might not work as label is inheriting CSS from Bootstrap label.