# How can we align texts vertically (but keep left align) in the center of a column?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

How can I align my text (consisting of a `<h1>` and a `<h3>`) that is inside a column taking up 7/12 of the width of the row in the vertical center? I want them to be left aligned but vertically in the center as there is an image in the other 5/12 of the row. Thanks if anyone knows!

Here is my html code:

```
<hr>
<div class="row detail">
    <div class="col-md-7 detail-texts">
      <h1 class="">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It'll blow your mind.</span></h1>
      <h3 class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="assets/500x500.jpg" alt="grey box"> 
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

        <div class="row detail">
          <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2 detail-texts">
            <h1 class="">Oh yeah, it's that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h1>
            <h3 class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="assets/500x500.jpg" alt="grey box">   
        </div>
        </div>

        <hr>
```

And here is my SCSS file:

```
.detail{padding: 6%;
color:#5a5a5a;

&-texts{padding: 0;}

}
hr{width:88%;}
    
img{width: 500px;
   height: 500px;}

display:flex;
align-items: center;
```

and

```
display:flex;
    align-self: center;
```

On  `.details-texts` and it does not work

Edit: adding `d-flex` and `align-self-center` classes works. Does anyone know how this is different from the `display:flex` method?

Comment: Use flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ or as that looks like bootstrap you can use it's built in utility classes like "align-items-center"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical Align Center in Bootstrap 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap-4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox to do this.

```
.detail-texts{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first too! But it doesn't work, I tried `align-self`  instead of `align-items` too. I am reading some documentations now, will post when I find the answer

Comment: Check that styles are not being trodden with bootstrap ... in that case, you can use !Important

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found the solution: adding the class `d-flex` to my div with the `row` and adding `align-self-center` to the div class right inside it works. I am not sure how this is different from adding

```
display: flex;
align-self: center;
```

into SCSS because it's supposed to be the same thing so this is the only doubt I have thanks!