# How to add Bootstrap 5 padding uniformly across sides?

Tags: css, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am trying to experiment with Bootstrap 5 within React, but somehow fail to understand the padding and margin. Consider the following code:

```
const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={"bg-dark rounded-start"}>
            <Breadcrumb>
                <Breadcrumb.Item href="#">Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
                <Breadcrumb.Item href="https://somelink.com">
                    Library
                </Breadcrumb.Item>
                <Breadcrumb.Item active>Data</Breadcrumb.Item>
            </Breadcrumb>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Its a Component which is later on shown in a `Container`. I chose a dark background to better show the issue. With this code, the Breadcrumbs render like this:

[image: Breadcrumbs without modifiers]

Now I want them to have some padding within the surrounding box, lets say only in vertical direction. According to the [Spacing documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) I should be adding modifier classes, for example `py-2` which should add a Padding to both top and bottom to `$spacer * .5`. When applying the additional class like this:

```
const Breadcrumbs = (props) => {

    return (
        <div className={"bg-dark py-2 rounded-start"}>
            <Breadcrumb>
                <Breadcrumb.Item href="#">Home</Breadcrumb.Item>
                <Breadcrumb.Item href="https://somelink.com">
                    Library
                </Breadcrumb.Item>
                <Breadcrumb.Item active>Data</Breadcrumb.Item>
            </Breadcrumb>
        </div>
    )
}
```

It now looks like this:

[image: Breadcrubs with padding]

My question now is: how can I add padding that keeps the Breacrumbs *vertically* centered within the surrounding div?

//Edit: I think I found something. The `<ol>` element created by `Breadcrumb` has a `margin-bottom` set. How can I remove that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252443/vertical-align-center-in-bootstrap

Comment: I honestly don' think that answers the question. Without padding, its no padding on top or bottom. Adding the same padding to top and bottom yields a result where there is more space on the bottom than the top. This is what I'd like to understand.