# How to append the bootstrap 5 dropdown menu to a specific element. when the dropdown element is inside an element with overflow: hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am use [Bootstrap 5 dropdown menu](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#options) inside owl-carousel. but dropdown is being cut off because has outer div `overflow:hidden` in owl-carousel.

[image]

**Complete snippet here:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harnishdesign/obg7favd/9/)

So, I have try to position a dropdown relatively to body, not parent with boundary option from [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#options),

Bootstrap docs says that can only be done via javascript (not via data attributes),

so I have try below javascript methods code. but no luck.

```
var dropdownElementList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-toggle'))
    var dropdownList = dropdownElementList.map(function (dropdownToggleEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Dropdown(dropdownToggleEl, {
        boundary: document.querySelector('#main-wrapper')
      })
    })
```

Any suggestions with proper solution for where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

**Our HTML Code:**

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <h4>Shilipp Sotocnik</h4>
      
      <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
      <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well when it has overflow hidden all overflow will be hidden. You can either add a lot of bottom padding or try overflow-x hidden and y show

Comment: @Alex it is not proper solution. Here, I want to dropdown append in body or other outer element. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid changing the properties of the carousel blocks, adding extra layout blocks, and playing with the `overflow` property, we can move the dropdown menu outside of the carousel.

1. the [`.each()` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) goes through all the carousels on the page;
2. the [`.on()` method](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) with a selector attachs a delegated event handler for events from the item clones that can be created by the Owl Carousel at a later time;
3. the [`show.bs.dropdown` event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#events) fires immediately when the show method is called;
4. the [`getInstance` method](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/#methods) returns the dropdown instance associated to a DOM element;
5. the [`.insertAfter()` method](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) inserts element after the target.

In our case the dropdown menus will be moved, not copied:

> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved after the target (not cloned) and a new set consisting of the inserted element is returned

And I think we do not need to return them to their original place after closing. If this is still needed, then this can be done by analogy with the `hidden.bs.dropdown` event.

https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/s0yua1w7/

```js
$(function() {

  $('.owl-carousel')
    .each(function() {
      let carousel = $(this);
      carousel.on('show.bs.dropdown', '[data-bs-toggle=dropdown]', function() {
        // universal solution
        let dropdown = bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance(this);
        $(dropdown._menu).insertAfter(carousel);

                // alternative for this particular layout
        // $(this).next('.dropdown-menu').insertAfter(carousel);
      });
    })
    .owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:15,
      nav:true,
    });

});
```

```html
<div class="py-5 mx-4">

  <h2>First Owl Carousel</h2>

  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 1</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 2</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 3</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu3" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 4</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu4" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu4">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 10</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 11</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2>Second Owl Carousel</h2>

  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 1</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu21" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu21">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 2</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu22" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu22">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 3</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu23" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu23">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="item card">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3">
        <h5>Shilipp Sotocnik 4</h5>
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg d-inline-block ms-auto"> 
          <a href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenu24" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu24">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 6</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 7</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 8</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 10</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 11</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <p class="px-3">
        Lorem ipsum dummy
      </p>    
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt doloribus ipsa at culpa fugit nesciunt nulla rem inventore eum perspiciatis assumenda ipsam aut architecto unde laboriosam totam fuga in, dolore.</p>
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is working perfectly as i want. Just one question. Yes. we do not need to return them to their original place after closing. but, though, if we will want in future. So, what can i use method in `hidden.bs.dropdown` ? Here I have used your alternative method. `$(this).next('.dropdown-menu').insertAfter(carousel);`. So, it does move after click dropdown. Thanks.

Comment: The general idea is to go in reverse order: add a `hidden.bs.dropdown` event handler, and inside it also define an anchored dropdown menu and put it next to the link. To do this, you can copy and edit the code for `show.bs.dropdown`. Something like: 
`carousel.on('hidden.bs.dropdown', '[data-bs-toggle=dropdown]', function() { let dropdown = bootstrap.Dropdown.getInstance(this); $(dropdown._menu).insertAfter(dropdown);  });`
But it's necessary to test how reliably this works, taking into account the clones that the carousel creates.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to listen events on dropdown to toggle overflow class at element

`<div class="owl-stage-outer">`.

```js
$('a[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(".owl-stage-outer").addClass("overflow_none");
})

$('a[data-bs-toggle="dropdown"]').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(".owl-stage-outer").removeClass("overflow_none");
})
```

```css
.overflow_none  {
  overflow: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: This is not proper solution. It will create horizontal scrollbar in browser that time. We can't tamper with overflow. Here, we must need to append dropdown in other element like body.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this in css?

```
.owl-stage-outer {
  overflow: visible !important;  
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have try this. but, It will create horizontal scrollbar and show other hide items in owl-carousel. We can't tamper with overflow in owl-carousel. Here, we must need to append dropdown in other element like body.

Answer (score 0):

Does the overflow hidden property really need to be there?

Alternatively, if you are using one class with the overflow hidden attribute, you could make an exception to this one div. To do that, give an ID to the specific div you want to target, now add overflow: visible !important; to that div.

Comment: Yes, overflow hidden property must need to be there. otherwise, carousel/slider not work properly. The overflow hidden property is there in all sliders/carousels. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is what actually happens when you activate `owl-carousel`, see the markup below-

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage">
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not gonna talk about `dots` or `nav`, those aren't relevant here. I want to bring your attention to the class named- `owl-stage-outer`. this is the class that contains the CSS of `overflow: hidden;`. These 2 classes- `owl-stage-outer` & `owl-stage` are generated from `owl-carousel`.

To prevent this, you can add a Bootstrap class `.overflow-visible` with `owl-stage-outer`. Since the `owl-stage-outer` class is not hard-code markup, there is an option in [owl-carousel doc](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html) to customize this class. See the picture below, it's from the doc page- [image]

Now, another issue could appear, since you added `.overflow-visible` class with  `owl-stage-outer`, the `items` that should be outside of the view, some of them will be visible now. To prevent that you will need to change a little bit of markup and add one line of CSS.

[In this example](https://jsfiddle.net/harnishdesign/obg7favd/9/), you have `px-4` Bootstrap class in your `main-wrapper` `id`, change the `px-4` to `mx-4` and add the CSS of `overflow-x: hidden;` to `#main-wrapper`

And that's it, this could help you fix the issue. [Here is the live fixed version](https://jsfiddle.net/tanim_mahbub/Lfd1a5h6/5/) of what I'm trying to say, good luck.

### Update

Since our [current example](https://jsfiddle.net/tanim_mahbub/Lfd1a5h6/7/) is having a scrollbar when dropdown menu is triggered, I have made some changes in CSS only-

```css
body {overflow-x: hidden;}

#main-wrapper .owl-item {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

#main-wrapper .owl-item.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Here is the live example](https://jsfiddle.net/tanim_mahbub/fk27yaoh/46/).

Comment: Thanks but, This is temporary solution. When will add more link item in dropdown. means, when dropdown more long. So, It will same issue. please check this - https://jsfiddle.net/harnishdesign/qdyh61vs/1/

Comment: @HDP [Check out this update](https://jsfiddle.net/tanim_mahbub/fk27yaoh/46/) and lemme know if it works for you, then I'll update my answer accordingly.