# How can I setattribute in popover by using JavaScript in bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to set html attribute in popover by using JavaScript in bootstrap 5. But I can't.

Here is my popover code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-3" id="popcart" data-bs-html="true" 
      data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- 
      content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
```

Java script code:

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id="popcart"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, 

    {
      html: true
    })
})
document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content','<h5>Cart</h5>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `setAttribute` before all code like: ***(see update below)***

```js
document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart</h5>');
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id="popcart"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,

    {
      html: true
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-3" id="popcart" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
```

---

I had missed a giant mistake, the id **must** be unique instead use `data-id` like:

```js
document.querySelector('[data-id="popcart"]').setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart</h5>');
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-id="popcart"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,

    {
      html: true
    })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-3" data-id="popcart" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs-content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
```

Comment: It's works!!. Thanks a lot. @Simone Rossaini

Comment: See my update please @JonyGhosh

Comment: Now it's working fine. Thank you  @Simone Rossaini

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can you help any for this -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031318/how-to-append-the-bootstrap-5-dropdown-menu-to-a-specific-element-when-the-drop

Answer (score 2):

You can use spread to convert querySelectorAll collections to array:

```
   [...document.querySelectorAll(someSelector)].map(...)
```

BUT

IDs need to be unique

```js
const cart = document.getElementById("popcart");
cart.setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart</h5>');
var popoverList = new bootstrap.Popover(cart, { html: true });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mx-3" id="popcart" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
```

If you have more than one, use a class

```js
const popoverList = [...document.querySelectorAll(".popcart")].map(but => {
  but.setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart</h5>');
  return new bootstrap.Popover(but, {
    html: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button type="button" class="popcart btn btn-secondary mx-3" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
<button type="button" class="popcart btn btn-secondary mx-3" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-container="body" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom" data-bs- content="Bottom popover">Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>) </button>
```

Comment: I had not seen it, I also added the correction myself.