# ngx-dropdown positioning in bootstrap 5 sidebar bottom element is off

Tags: angular, dropdown, bootstrap-5, ngx-bootstrap

I am having difficulty with dropdown positioning. Created two examples on [stackblitz](/questions/tagged/stackblitz):
https://angular-ivy-cjl7md.stackblitz.io/?collapsed=false
https://angular-ivy-cjl7md.stackblitz.io/?collapsed=true

I was using 1:1 examples from [bootstrap-5](/questions/tagged/bootstrap-5). Example above is using header, sidebar with dropdown and footer.

The problem, that I encountered is with user panel in sidebar (**both collapsed and expanded view**):

| example 1 | example 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 1] | [image: 2] |

I tried to append dropdown to body, but that didn't help. Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: maybe this similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031318/how-to-append-the-bootstrap-5-dropdown-menu-to-a-specific-element-when-the-drop

Comment: The issue is, that OG sidebar element works fine here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/sidebars/. The problem appears once I use specifically ngx-bootstrap dropdown, which I would like to use.

Answer (score 1):

ok, after investigating your stackblitz I noticed you have this class:

```
 .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}
```

This conflicts with a class with the same name from ngx-bootstrap

removing the class fixes it

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kv8ime

**Edit**

Updated the code to still keep the Type to filter dropdowns. Just create a different class for it and add on top

```
.my-dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 4rem auto;
}
```

and on the html

```
class="dropdown-menu my-dropdown-menu ..."
```

I updated the stackblitz to handle that.

Comment: Unfortunately, removing that would result in "Type to filter" dropdowns to disappear

Comment: Yeah. But in any case I will update the code to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it is add another class to your `<ul>` dropdown menu and style it differently

app.component.html (notice the fix class next to dropdown-menu class):

```
<ul
    class="dropdown-menu fix text-small shadow"
    *dropdownMenu
    aria-labelledby="dropdownUser2"
>
      <!--dropdown items here-->
</ul>
```

app.component.scss

```
.fix {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -210px;
}
```